# jQuery AJAX pass url as string

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax function that is passing a string of variables to my script but I have one variable that needs to contain a full url with parameters.

What happens is that var1 and var2 become $_POST variables but I need to save the whole url variable as a string.

```
var url = "http://domain.com/index.php?var1=blah&var2=blah";

var dataArray = "rooftop_id=" +rooftop_id+ "&url=" +url;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/scripts/error_check.php",
            data: dataArray,
            dataType: 'json'
        });
```

I would like my $_POST variable to look like this:

```
$_POST['rooftop_id'] would be '1234'
$_POST['url'] would be 'http://domain.com/index.php?var1=blah&var2=blah'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's still missing quotes ? Did you try it like this **http://jsfiddle.net/6ZUzh/1/**

Comment: url: MISSING QUOTE HERE /scripts/error_check.php",

Comment: Thanks! I had the quote on my testing code but passing the variables individually worked.

Comment: You should do this on PHP side instead, or just use GET ;)

Answer (score 8):

Use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on url variable:

```
var url = "http://domain.com/index.php?var1=blah&var2=blah";

var dataArray = "rooftop_id=1&url=" +encodeURIComponent(url);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/scripts/error_check.php",
    data: dataArray,
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to build your form data by hand. jQuery will encode it for you (with appropriate escaping) if you pass it an object.

```
var url = "http://domain.com/index.php?var1=blah&var2=blah";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/scripts/error_check.php",
    data: { url: url, rooftop_id: rooftop_id },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```