# Ajax request not passing whole the string?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to send a string to a php file using ajax using this code, but when i `echo $_POST['dnload'];` it only prints out https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download instead of the whole string in the console.

```
var download = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=";
var id="1a4mib5pVOGIzBTxjGmvVwx-0uvK2NqaR";


$("#search").on("click", function(){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var main = mainlink+id;
    var thumb = thumbnail+id;
    var dnload = download+id;
    http.open("POST", 'walldb.php', true);
    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    http.onload = function(){
        if (this.status == 200){
        console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    }
    http.send("main=" + main + "&thumb=" +thumb + "&dnload=" +dnload);
});
```

Comment: So you are sending something, which is separated by `&`, and one of the contents contains a `&`.

Comment: but urlencoded should fix that? no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i researched a bit and finally found a solution so thought i'd post an answer 
i changed:

```
var dnload = download+id;
```

to:

```
var dnload = encodeURIComponent(download) + id;
```

thanks! :)

heres where i found the solution : [jQuery AJAX pass url as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837470/jquery-ajax-pass-url-as-string)